# How to Repair System Files on Windows 7, after sfc /scannow fails?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Windows 7 (x64) to Windows 10.

The upgrade fails.  I've followed most of the [suggestions from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/quick-fixes), including running SFC.

1. When I run **SFC /Scannow**  it fails with the error:     *Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.*  Error log for this is below.
2. I then ran:

   ```
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

However, when I do that I get an error message:
*The restorehealth option is not recognized for this context.*

---

**Error log** from above failure to fix:
(I'm including only some of the  "cannot repair" entries because I can't include the whole Log file here (limited on Total Characters in question):

```
2022-01-11 20:42:19, Info                  CSI    00000213 [SR] **Cannot repair member** file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\EP0NGPUL.GPD" of prnep00b.inf, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing



2022-01-11 20:42:19, Info                  CSI    00000214 [SR] **Cannot repair member file** [l:36{18}]"Amd64\EP0NGPUL.GPD" of prnep00b.inf, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2022-01-11 20:42:19, Info                  CSI    00000215 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:186{93}]"Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.INF_prnep00b"
2022-01-11 20:42:20, Info                  CSI    00000216 Repair results created:
```

....
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;3
2022-01-11 20:43:17, Info                  CSI    00000385 [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired

Comment: It would be more helpful to know why w10 install failed by looking at the upgrade logs

Answer (score 0):

This PC had some Services disabled on startup (with System Config).
Enabled all services and the DISM command ran OK.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run SFC /Scannow it fails with the error: Windows Resource
> Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
> Error log for this is below.

Windows 7 does not have the repair facilities that later operating systems have.

If you have the original Windows 7 DVD that you used to install your system, you can start from that DVD and you should have an option to repair your operating system as one of the selections after starting from the DVD.

Try that.

(a) Be sure you have a back up of your important documents first.

(b) If the repair fails, you would need to reinstall Windows 7.  You will need to download Windows 7 SP1 (the SP1 file) and install that and then see if Windows 7 Update can do the remaining updates.

From there you may be able to do the Windows 10 upgrade.

(c) Your last option is to try to install Windows 10 directly (not as an upgrade).